# Jquery toggle hover flickering

Tags: jquery, html

This is kind of odd. I have a social button that when you hover over it the social icons are supposed to show up. This works, but the hover is flickering.

I captured a screencast of it so you know I just don't have bad eyesight. :)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GDcfsG6Frg&feature=youtu.be

and the html looks like this

```
<div  class="social">Be Social!</div>
<div class="socialBttn">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="<?= base_url('assets/img/facebook.png') ?>" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="<?= base_url('assets/img/twitter.png') ?>" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="<?= base_url('assets/img/link.png') ?>" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="<?= base_url('assets/img/google.png') ?>" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the jquery looks like this

```
$(".social").hover(function () {
   $(".socialBttn").toggle();
});
```

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write up `CSS` for the same instead of `jQuery`

As the `hover` event keeps firing continuously as long as there is a minor movement over the div. So you see the ripple effect.

```
.social + .socialBttn{
    display: none;
}

.social:hover + .socialBttn{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You are amazing! I didn't even think of using css! If I could I would hug you!

Comment: haha.. Happens with everyone once in a while. So don worry :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you set each of the mini-images to visible via `$.toggle()`, if your mouse now hovers over one of those images, it will trigger the hover event again on the `.social` div and trigger it once more for hovering over one of the new elements inside `.social` div.

Comment: But the hover is not on the images, it's only on the social tab.

Comment: I know, but browsers will still do it, you technically are hovering over the new element so it triggers the hover on the old element again, and since the new element is inside the parent, the event bubbles up and triggers it again.  Something like that anyway.

Comment: Thats strange. I built my html the way it was so there wouldn't be parent child issues. Browsers are weird.